# Accessing SessionFactory from Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

Jhipster is based on Spring-boot, how can I access Hibernate SessionFactory from a Service in Jhipster. I would like to execute a raw SQL query so I need to create Session.createSQLQuery...
I noticed that EntityFactory is used in CacheConfiguration but if I try to inject it as a bean in my Service, I got a NullPointer exception...

Thanks,
O.

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it. We simply need to add

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

protected Session getCurrentSession()  {
    return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
}
```

in the service class.
Then, in the method, juste create the hibernate session :

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();
```

My mystake was that I wanted to create Hibernate Session in the constructor of the service.